# json javascript filter value on key

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

The final output should be a list of all images having the desktop_categories: Jackpots.

The All Games button displays all images:

```
//List all images in the ol #oneall
        $.each(data.items, function(i, f) {
            $("#oneall").append("<li><img src='" + f.image_180x100 + "' / ></li>");

        });
```

The two other buttons: popular games and slots, have to display images according to their desktop_categories: Slots and Popular Games.

I hope this makes more sense. 
In order to keep things simple (as my javascript level is beginner), I am trying to output the title with the value: "Vikingmania".

But this part doesn't work:

```
//filter all title with the value "Vikingmania". This part doesn't work     
        $.filter(data.items, function(x) { return x.title.search("Vikingmania");
                                        $("#twopopular").append("<li><p>'" + x.title + "'</p></li>");
                                      });
```

The console says this part is unreachable:

```
$("#twopopular").append("<li><p>'" + x.title + "'</p></li>");
```

(unreachable code after return statement)

and the return statement is undefined:

```
return x.title.search("Vikingmania");
```

TypeError: elem is undefined

```
return elems.length === 1 && elem.nodeType === 1 ?


<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>game</title>
    <link href="//cdn.rawgit.com/noelboss/featherlight/1.7.5/release/featherlight.min.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link>
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
    <script src="//cdn.rawgit.com/noelboss/featherlight/1.7.5/release/featherlight.min.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>

    <!--<script type="text/javascript" src="foo.js"></script>-->
    <style>
        li {
            float: left;
        }

        ol {
            list-style-type: none;
        }

        div {
            display: none;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <h3>Test</h3>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="all">All Games</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="jackpots">Jackpots</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="popular">Popular Games</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="slots">Slots</button>
    <div id="one">
        <ol id="oneall">
            <li data-featherlight></li>
        </ol>
    </div>

    <div id="two">
        <ol id="twopopular"></ol>
    </div>

    <script>
        var data = {
            "items": [{
                    "title": "Frankie Dettori",
                    "image_180x100": "https://www.supercasino.com/assets/GB/games/sc_fdt_180x100.jpg",
                    "desktop_categories_ids": "39,3,79",
                    "desktop_categories": "Popular Games,Slots,All Games"
                }, {
                    "title": "Frankie Dettori",
                    "image_180x100": "https://www.supercasino.com/assets/GB/games/sc_fdt_180x100.jpg",
                    "desktop_categories_ids": "39,3,79",
                    "desktop_categories": "Popular Games,Slots,All Games"
                }, {
                    "title": "Desert Treasure Desktop",
                    "image_180x100": "https://www.supercasino.com/assets/GB/games/sc_dt_180x100.jpg",
                    "desktop_categories_ids": "3,79",
                    "desktop_categories": "Slots,All Games"
                }, {
                    "title": "Vacation Station",
                    "image_180x100": "https://www.supercasino.com/assets/GB/games/sc_er_180x100.jpg",
                    "desktop_categories_ids": "3,79",
                    "desktop_categories": "Slots,All Games"
                }, {
                    "title": "Vacation Station",
                    "image_180x100": "https://www.supercasino.com/assets/GB/games/sc_er_180x100.jpg",
                    "desktop_categories_ids": "3,79",
                    "desktop_categories": "Slots,All Games"
                }, {
                    "title": "Hulk 25 Line",
                    "image_180x100": "https://www.supercasino.com/assets/GB/games/Hulk_180x100.jpg",
                    "desktop_categories_ids": "39,3,4,79",
                    "desktop_categories": "Popular Games,Slots,Jackpots,All Games"
                }, {
                    "title": "Jackpot Darts",
                    "image_180x100": "https://www.supercasino.com/assets/GB/games/sc_drts_180x100.jpg",
                    "desktop_categories_ids": "3,4,79",
                    "desktop_categories": "Slots,Jackpots,All Games"
                }, {
                    "title": "Genie Hi-Lo",
                    "image_180x100": "https://www.supercasino.com/assets/GB/games/sc_ghl_180x100.jpg",
                    "desktop_categories_ids": "79",
                    "desktop_categories": "All Games"
                }, {
                    "title": "Gladiator",
                    "image_180x100": "https://www.supercasino.com/assets/GB/games/sc_glr_180x100.jpg",
                    "desktop_categories_ids": "39,3,79",
                    "desktop_categories": "Popular Games,Slots,All Games"
                }, {
                    "title": "Mr.Cashback",
                    "image_180x100": "https://www.supercasino.com/assets/GB/games/sc-mcb-180x100.jpg",
                    "desktop_categories_ids": "3,79",
                    "desktop_categories": "Slots,All Games"
                }, {
                    "title": "Great Blue",
                    "image_180x100": "https://www.supercasino.com/assets/GB/games/sc-bib-180x100.jpg",
                    "desktop_categories_ids": "39,3,79",
                    "desktop_categories": "Popular Games,Slots,All Games"
                }, {
                    "title": "Wild Games",
                    "image_180x100": "https://www.supercasino.com/assets/GB/games/SC_WILDGAMES_180x100.jpg",
                    "desktop_categories_ids": "3,79",
                    "desktop_categories": "Slots,All Games"
                }, {
                    "title": "Kong: Eighth Wonder of the World",
                    "image_180x100": "https://www.supercasino.com/assets/GB/games/SC_Kong_180x100.jpg",
                    "desktop_categories_ids": "3,79",
                    "desktop_categories": "Slots,All Games"
                }, {
                    "title": "Iron Man 2 - 25 Line",
                    "image_180x100": "https://www.supercasino.com/assets/GB/games/Ironman2_180x100.jpg",
                    "desktop_categories_ids": "3,4,79",
                    "desktop_categories": "Slots,Jackpots,All Games"
                }, {
                    "title": "Iron Man",
                    "image_180x100": "https://www.supercasino.com/assets/GB/games/IronMan_180x100.jpg",
                    "desktop_categories_ids": "3,4,79",
                    "desktop_categories": "Slots,Jackpots,All Games"
                }, {
                    "title": "UK Blackjack",
                    "image_180x100": "https://www.supercasino.com/assets/GB/games/sc_bjuk_180x100_v2.jpg",
                    "desktop_categories_ids": "2,79",
                    "desktop_categories": "Blackjack,All Games"
                }, {
                    "title": "21 Duel Blackjack",
                    "image_180x100": "https://www.supercasino.com/assets/GB/games/sc_bj21d_180x100_v2.jpg",
                    "desktop_categories_ids": "2,79",
                    "desktop_categories": "Blackjack,All Games"
                }, {
                    "title": "Fantastic Four",
                    "image_180x100": "https://www.supercasino.com/assets/GB/games/FantasticFour_super_180x100.jpg",
                    "desktop_categories_ids": "3,4,79",
                    "desktop_categories": "Slots,Jackpots,All Games"
                },

                {
                    "title": "The Mummy",
                    "image_180x100": "https://www.supercasino.com/assets/GB/games/SC_GAME_MUMMY.jpg",
                    "desktop_categories_ids": "3,79",
                    "desktop_categories": "Slots,All Games"
                }, {
                    "title": "Desert Treasure II",
                    "image_180x100": "https://www.supercasino.com/assets/GB/games/sc-dt2-180x100.jpg",
                    "desktop_categories_ids": "3,79",
                    "desktop_categories": "Slots,All Games"
                }, {
                    "title": "X Men",
                    "image_180x100": "https://www.supercasino.com/assets/GB/games/Xmen_180x100.jpg",
                    "desktop_categories_ids": "3,4,79",
                    "desktop_categories": "Slots,Jackpots,All Games"
                }, {
                    "title": "Daredevil",
                    "image_180x100": "https://www.supercasino.com/assets/GB/games/Daredevil_180x100.jpg",
                    "desktop_categories_ids": "3,4,79",
                    "desktop_categories": "Slots,Jackpots,All Games"
                }, {
                    "title": "Rocky",
                    "image_180x100": "https://www.supercasino.com/assets/GB/games/sc_rky_180x100.jpg",
                    "desktop_categories_ids": "3,79",
                    "desktop_categories": "Slots,All Games"
                }, {
                    "title": "Hulk 50 Line",
                    "image_180x100": "https://www.supercasino.com/assets/GB/games/Hulk50_180x100.jpg",
                    "desktop_categories_ids": "3,4,79",
                    "desktop_categories": "Slots,Jackpots,All Games"
                }, {
                    "title": "Football Fans",
                    "image_180x100": "https://www.supercasino.com/assets/GB/games/SC_GAME_FOOTBALL_FANS.jpg",
                    "desktop_categories_ids": "3,79",
                    "desktop_categories": "Slots,All Games"
                }, {
                    "title": "Hot Gems",
                    "image_180x100": "https://www.supercasino.com/assets/GB/games/SC_GAME_HOT_GEMS.jpg",
                    "desktop_categories_ids": "3,79",
                    "desktop_categories": "Slots,All Games"
                }, {
                    "title": "Wings of Gold",
                    "image_180x100": "https://www.supercasino.com/assets/GB/games/SC_GAME_WINGS_OF_GOLD.jpg",
                    "desktop_categories_ids": "3,79",
                    "desktop_categories": "Slots,All Games"
                }, {
                    "title": "Goddess of Life",
                    "image_180x100": "https://www.supercasino.com/assets/GB/games/SC_GAME_GODDESS_OF_LIFE.jpg",
                    "desktop_categories_ids": "3,79",
                    "desktop_categories": "Slots,All Games"
                }, {
                    "title": "Vikingmania",
                    "image_180x100": "https://www.supercasino.com/assets/GB/games/SC_GAME_VIKING_MANIA.jpg",
                    "desktop_categories_ids": "3,79",
                    "desktop_categories": "Slots,All Games"
                }, {
                    "title": "Elektra",
                    "image_180x100": "https://www.supercasino.com/assets/GB/games/Elektra_180x100.jpg",
                    "desktop_categories_ids": "3,4,79",
                    "desktop_categories": "Slots,Jackpots,All Games"
                }, {
                    "title": "Fantastic Four 50 Line",
                    "image_180x100": "https://www.supercasino.com/assets/GB/games/FantasticFour50_super_180x100.jpg",
                    "desktop_categories_ids": "39,3,4,79",
                    "desktop_categories": "Popular Games,Slots,Jackpots,All Games"
                }, {
                    "title": "Iron Man 2 50 Line",
                    "image_180x100": "https://www.supercasino.com/assets/GB/games/IronMan250_180x100.jpg",
                    "desktop_categories_ids": "3,4,79",
                    "desktop_categories": "Slots,Jackpots,All Games"
                }, {
                    "title": "Wild Spirit",
                    "image_180x100": "https://www.supercasino.com/assets/GB/games/SC_WILDSPIRIT_180x100.jpg",
                    "desktop_categories_ids": "3,79",
                    "desktop_categories": "Slots,All Games"
                }
            ]
        };
//List all images in the ol #oneall
        $.each(data.items, function(i, f) {
            $("#oneall").append("<li><img src='" + f.image_180x100 + "' / ></li>");

        });

//toggles the div #one with the ol #oneall  
         $('#all').click(function() {
            $("#one").toggle();
        });


//filter all title with the value "Vikingmania". This part doesn't work     
        $.filter(data.items, function(x) { return x.title.search("Vikingmania");
                                        $("#twopopular").append("<li><p>'" + x.title + "'</p></li>");
                                      }); 



        //toggles the div #two with the ol #twopopular
        $('#popular').click(function() {
            $("#two").toggle();
        });

    </script>

</body>

</html>
```

This task should be so easy, but I can't seem to get the right result and I am new to json/javascript. 
I need to sort desktop_categories according to their value: Popular Games, Slot, All Games, Jackpots..etc. In a click function. 
To start with I am trying to parse the data as an array. 
I am trying to list  all desktop_categories with the value of Jackpots. 
Instead I get all the desktop_categories.
What am I doing wrong?
Help much appreciated.

```js
    var json = [{
        "title": "Frankie Dettori",
        "image_180x100": "https://www.supercasino.com/assets/GB/games/sc_fdt_180x100.jpg",
        "desktop_categories_ids": "39,3,79",
        "desktop_categories": "Popular Games,Slots,All Games"
      },
      {
        "title": "Frankie Dettori",
        "image_180x100": "https://www.supercasino.com/assets/GB/games/sc_fdt_180x100.jpg",
        "desktop_categories_ids": "39,3,79",
        "desktop_categories": "Popular Games,Slots,All Games"
      },
      {
        "title": "Desert Treasure Desktop",
        "image_180x100": "https://www.supercasino.com/assets/GB/games/sc_dt_180x100.jpg",
        "desktop_categories_ids": "3,79",
        "desktop_categories": "Slots,All Games"
      },
      {
        "title": "Vacation Station",
        "image_180x100": "https://www.supercasino.com/assets/GB/games/sc_er_180x100.jpg",
        "desktop_categories_ids": "3,79",
        "desktop_categories": "Slots,All Games"
      },
      {
        "title": "Vacation Station",
        "image_180x100": "https://www.supercasino.com/assets/GB/games/sc_er_180x100.jpg",
        "desktop_categories_ids": "3,79",
        "desktop_categories": "Slots,All Games"
      },
      {
        "title": "Hulk 25 Line",
        "image_180x100": "https://www.supercasino.com/assets/GB/games/Hulk_180x100.jpg",
        "desktop_categories_ids": "39,3,4,79",
        "desktop_categories": "Popular Games,Slots,Jackpots,All Games"
      },
      {
        "title": "Jackpot Darts",
        "image_180x100": "https://www.supercasino.com/assets/GB/games/sc_drts_180x100.jpg",
        "desktop_categories_ids": "3,4,79",
        "desktop_categories": "Slots,Jackpots,All Games"
      },
      {
        "title": "Genie Hi-Lo",
        "image_180x100": "https://www.supercasino.com/assets/GB/games/sc_ghl_180x100.jpg",
        "desktop_categories_ids": "79",
        "desktop_categories": "All Games"
      },
      {
        "title": "Gladiator",
        "image_180x100": "https://www.supercasino.com/assets/GB/games/sc_glr_180x100.jpg",
        "desktop_categories_ids": "39,3,79",
        "desktop_categories": "Popular Games,Slots,All Games"
      },
      {
        "title": "Mr.Cashback",
        "image_180x100": "https://www.supercasino.com/assets/GB/games/sc-mcb-180x100.jpg",
        "desktop_categories_ids": "3,79",
        "desktop_categories": "Slots,All Games"
      },
      {
        "title": "Great Blue",
        "image_180x100": "https://www.supercasino.com/assets/GB/games/sc-bib-180x100.jpg",
        "desktop_categories_ids": "39,3,79",
        "desktop_categories": "Popular Games,Slots,All Games"
      },
      {
        "title": "Wild Games",
        "image_180x100": "https://www.supercasino.com/assets/GB/games/SC_WILDGAMES_180x100.jpg",
        "desktop_categories_ids": "3,79",
        "desktop_categories": "Slots,All Games"
      },
      {
        "title": "Kong: Eighth Wonder of the World",
        "image_180x100": "https://www.supercasino.com/assets/GB/games/SC_Kong_180x100.jpg",
        "desktop_categories_ids": "3,79",
        "desktop_categories": "Slots,All Games"
      },
      {
        "title": "Iron Man 2 - 25 Line",
        "image_180x100": "https://www.supercasino.com/assets/GB/games/Ironman2_180x100.jpg",
        "desktop_categories_ids": "3,4,79",
        "desktop_categories": "Slots,Jackpots,All Games"
      },
      {
        "title": "Iron Man",
        "image_180x100": "https://www.supercasino.com/assets/GB/games/IronMan_180x100.jpg",
        "desktop_categories_ids": "3,4,79",
        "desktop_categories": "Slots,Jackpots,All Games"
      },
      {
        "title": "UK Blackjack",
        "image_180x100": "https://www.supercasino.com/assets/GB/games/sc_bjuk_180x100_v2.jpg",
        "desktop_categories_ids": "2,79",
        "desktop_categories": "Blackjack,All Games"
      },
      {
        "title": "21 Duel Blackjack",
        "image_180x100": "https://www.supercasino.com/assets/GB/games/sc_bj21d_180x100_v2.jpg",
        "desktop_categories_ids": "2,79",
        "desktop_categories": "Blackjack,All Games"
      },
      {
        "title": "Fantastic Four",
        "image_180x100": "https://www.supercasino.com/assets/GB/games/FantasticFour_super_180x100.jpg",
        "desktop_categories_ids": "3,4,79",
        "desktop_categories": "Slots,Jackpots,All Games"
      },
    
      {
        "title": "The Mummy",
        "image_180x100": "https://www.supercasino.com/assets/GB/games/SC_GAME_MUMMY.jpg",
        "desktop_categories_ids": "3,79",
        "desktop_categories": "Slots,All Games"
      },
      {
        "title": "Desert Treasure II",
        "image_180x100": "https://www.supercasino.com/assets/GB/games/sc-dt2-180x100.jpg",
        "desktop_categories_ids": "3,79",
        "desktop_categories": "Slots,All Games"
      },
      {
        "title": "X Men",
        "image_180x100": "https://www.supercasino.com/assets/GB/games/Xmen_180x100.jpg",
        "desktop_categories_ids": "3,4,79",
        "desktop_categories": "Slots,Jackpots,All Games"
      },
      {
        "title": "Daredevil",
        "image_180x100": "https://www.supercasino.com/assets/GB/games/Daredevil_180x100.jpg",
        "desktop_categories_ids": "3,4,79",
        "desktop_categories": "Slots,Jackpots,All Games"
      },
      {
        "title": "Rocky",
        "image_180x100": "https://www.supercasino.com/assets/GB/games/sc_rky_180x100.jpg",
        "desktop_categories_ids": "3,79",
        "desktop_categories": "Slots,All Games"
      },
      {
        "title": "Hulk 50 Line",
        "image_180x100": "https://www.supercasino.com/assets/GB/games/Hulk50_180x100.jpg",
        "desktop_categories_ids": "3,4,79",
        "desktop_categories": "Slots,Jackpots,All Games"
      },
      {
        "title": "Football Fans",
        "image_180x100": "https://www.supercasino.com/assets/GB/games/SC_GAME_FOOTBALL_FANS.jpg",
        "desktop_categories_ids": "3,79",
        "desktop_categories": "Slots,All Games"
      },
      {
        "title": "Hot Gems",
        "image_180x100": "https://www.supercasino.com/assets/GB/games/SC_GAME_HOT_GEMS.jpg",
        "desktop_categories_ids": "3,79",
        "desktop_categories": "Slots,All Games"
      },
      {
        "title": "Wings of Gold",
        "image_180x100": "https://www.supercasino.com/assets/GB/games/SC_GAME_WINGS_OF_GOLD.jpg",
        "desktop_categories_ids": "3,79",
        "desktop_categories": "Slots,All Games"
      },
      {
        "title": "Goddess of Life",
        "image_180x100": "https://www.supercasino.com/assets/GB/games/SC_GAME_GODDESS_OF_LIFE.jpg",
        "desktop_categories_ids": "3,79",
        "desktop_categories": "Slots,All Games"
      },
      {
        "title": "Vikingmania",
        "image_180x100": "https://www.supercasino.com/assets/GB/games/SC_GAME_VIKING_MANIA.jpg",
        "desktop_categories_ids": "3,79",
        "desktop_categories": "Slots,All Games"
      },
      {
        "title": "Elektra",
        "image_180x100": "https://www.supercasino.com/assets/GB/games/Elektra_180x100.jpg",
        "desktop_categories_ids": "3,4,79",
        "desktop_categories": "Slots,Jackpots,All Games"
      },
      {
        "title": "Fantastic Four 50 Line",
        "image_180x100": "https://www.supercasino.com/assets/GB/games/FantasticFour50_super_180x100.jpg",
        "desktop_categories_ids": "39,3,4,79",
        "desktop_categories": "Popular Games,Slots,Jackpots,All Games"
      },
      {
        "title": "Iron Man 2 50 Line",
        "image_180x100": "https://www.supercasino.com/assets/GB/games/IronMan250_180x100.jpg",
        "desktop_categories_ids": "3,4,79",
        "desktop_categories": "Slots,Jackpots,All Games"
      },
      {
        "title": "Wild Spirit",
        "image_180x100": "https://www.supercasino.com/assets/GB/games/SC_WILDSPIRIT_180x100.jpg",
        "desktop_categories_ids": "3,79",
        "desktop_categories": "Slots,All Games"
      }];
    
    
     var parsed = {};
    
    for (var i = 0, iLen = json.length; i < iLen; i++) {
      // Assuming all we need are the desktop_categories and a list
      var desktop_categories;
      var list = [];
    
      for (var key in json[i]) {
        var value = json[i][key];
    
        // We need to hold on to the desktop_categories with value "Jackpots"        
        if (key === "desktop_categories") {
          desktop_categories = value;
        } else if (value === "Jackpots") {
          list.push(key);
        }
      }
    
      // Add them to the parsed array 
      // List them in plain text
      parsed[desktop_categories] = list.join(", ");
    }
    
    // List them on the web page
    for (var key in parsed) {
      document.write(key + ": " + parsed[key] + "<br>");
    }
```

Comment: Maybe this helps `json.filter(function(x) {
  return x.desktop_categories.search("Jackpots")!=-1?true:false
}); `

Comment: @ErdoganOksuz you never need `condition ? true : false`, you can just pass the condition directly

Comment: It would be nice if you could show what you're expecting as the output, and what you're getting instead. Note that it's better to use `console.log(output)` rather than `document.write(output)`.

Answer (score 0):

A few things:

1) You only use the last value of `desktop_categories` because you overwrite it every time your for loop executes.

2) `value === "Jackpots"` is only true if `value` matches exactly, e.g. `"Jackpots,Slots" !== "Jackpots"`

3) Array methods (filter, map) are much more concise and legible.

Try printing the output to console or stepping through your code.

Comment: Thank you all. I have edited my question with the filter function. This part does not work: //filter all title with the value "Vikingmania". This part doesn't work  
  $.filter(data.items, function(x) { return x.title.search("Vikingmania");
            $("#twopopular").append("<li><p>'" + x.title + "'</p></li>");
           });